# connecting to sql server 2014 database from basic java application?

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea, sql-server-2014-express, connector-j

I am following along with the book "learn java for web development" by vishal layka at present. But I have run into an issue which I will describe as best I can here. Essentially I cant connect to my database called "book" with connectorj 5.0.8. the database is running locally on microsft sql server 2014. 
this is the method iam using to get the connection.

```
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
     return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books","eoin", "");
}
```

iam getting this output when iam trying to get the connection.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

 ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect
```

I edited my sql server configuration in the "sql server configuration manager" tool so that it operates on port 3306 and it is enabled on localhost. the service but still no joy. below shows an image of this config.

[image]

iam thinking maybe my lack of knowledge of sql server is holding me back here.
another thing i think that may be the issue is in sql management studio. 
when I try to change the login  properties password. this is circled in the image below.

[image]

when i change this password.then click "ok" then reenter the "login properties for this db user then password I previously changed seems to have returned to what it was originally? I may be barking up the wrong tree altogether but iam not too sure? I hope the question was clear enough and any help is appreciated!

just a quick edit. Ive also tried turning off my firewall completely and I still couldnt connect.

Comment: did you allow that the user eoin can login from another machine than localhost or a binded IP-Adress?

Comment: no i havent. do I need to connect from my ip address? I thought if the application is run locally i wouldnt need to do that. iam testing this out all on my own laptop. so iam not tyring to connect to a remote db

Comment: Oh yeah I see, sorry I thought you`d like to run this code on an android phone.

Comment: thanks anyway. yeah thought id jump over to web stuff now as my android is at a decent enough level now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your connection string is wrong.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books
```

Change it to

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/books
```

See [connection string info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx).

Second, you may need to open TCP/IP in protocol since by default SQL server express has only [Named Pipes open](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165677(v=sql.105).aspx). See how to [open TCP/IP Protocol here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: thanks ill give that a try. i have enabled TCP/IP ip address 127.0.0.1 on port 3306 if you look at the screen shot in the question above.

Comment: now i have . java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/books

Comment: Did you add driver to your classpath.

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin is under external directories.

Comment: You need SQL server driver.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong to use "jdbc:mysql" for MS SQL Server. If i`m rigth, try this [Building the Connection URL MS SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: is there a difference between the jar files i need to get? from what i see mysql and sqlserver are different jars?

Comment: Yes. You need to download jar for MS SQL https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Comment: cool. this doesnt seem to download when i try it though. maybe ill use a different browser

Comment: And maybe these links would be usefull [System Requirements for the JDBC Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422(v=sql.110).aspx) or [Overview of the JDBC Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378749(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: alright at leas tthat changed the exception being thrown. now iam getting "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 3306/books is not valid."

Comment: iam wondering if this is because i have java 1.8 that the jdbc for sql server 4.1 is not working?

Comment: You wrote "I cant connect to my database called **"book"**", but your url is 3306/book**s**

Comment: And url must be like this ``"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;databaseName=books;"``

Comment: cheers man, that helpd a lot. finally got it working. had to log in using windows authentication set myself as "db_reader". you answer helped me along the way.